# Is it possible make a service in angular without singleton?

Tags: angular, typescript, service, singleton

Morning,

I know that most use of Services in Angular is as singleton, to be able to share the same instance of the service with others modules.

However, I have a need in which I want each module that I provide the service in the section Providers be a new instance.

I explain: I have the services report-params-store-service that was created to save data params of reports. So I would like of injecting the report-params-store-service in, for example, INSS Reports, IRRF Reports, FGTS Reports, but that in each one of them was a isolated service, without singleton, because I am not wanna share datas params among the different reports that was injected by the same service report-params-store-service.

I am only wanna avoid repeating line code of the report-params-store-service having that to create one of him for each reports that I have.

Is it possible ? And how ?

I put the services in the providers in the each module that I needed but It behaved as a singleton service, sharing the data among the different modules.

Comment: You can provide the service at the component level. Hard to tell since we don't see your layout here but you likely have a root component for each module. Relying on lazy loading to accomplish this is fickle because you might refactor your code. Another option is to provide the service multiple times at the root level under different injection tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your service file change the following:

From:

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root',
})
```

To:

```
@Injectable()
```

Then provide your service in every module like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [ReportParamsStoreService ],
})
export class FeatureModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use-case is described in detail in angular's documentation: https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-by-lazy-loading-modules

> With providedIn: 'any', all eagerly loaded modules share a singleton instance; however, lazy loaded modules each get their own unique instance, as shown in the following diagram.

This mean you should set providedIn: 'any' to your service and add it to the providers array where needed (in your module or in your standalone component).

Please be aware that this applies only to lazy loaded modules, which is in general a best practice, but from your question it's not clear if you are using them. If you don't have them in place, please refer to Khumo Mogorosi's answer, since this is a more generic approach.